# FlexUnit test are inconsistent

Tags: actionscript-3, flexunit

Lately, my FlexUnit tests have become inconsistent. A specific test fails or passes in run mode randomly. If i run it in debug mode (without any breakpoints), it always passes.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Maybe some kind of race condition, pretty much impossible to tell without at least seeing the code in question.